# Second order differential equation (by Leonel)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, euclidean-geometry, physics, real-numbers

We have the following second order differential equation:

$\frac{d^{2}h}{dt^{2}}=9.81-\frac{5.2137\cdot\left(288.16-0.0065h\right)}{288.16}\cdot\left(\frac{dh}{dt}\right)^{2}\cdot0.3\cdot0.1063$

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything, maybe reducing to a simple case without all the constants floating around? Also, please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: Can you solve $\dot v=g-cv^2$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann you are missing a $h$ in $c$

Comment: Yes, this is a point to the first comment. My comment is still relevant for the level of knowledge, it's just less so.